# How did this character leave Endor's moon in the Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

After Rey defeats

> Kylo Ren on the remains of Death Star 2, she leaves using his TIE fighter. He is effectively marooned on the forest moon of Endor.

How did he leave the forest moon of Endor?

- Did he hijack a spaceship left by somebody else? (Maybe by Rey?)
- Did he hide aboard a ship crewed by the Resistance?
- Did he summon a spaceship from the First Order?

Comment: The film is a complete nonsense. We can teorize and use our imagination, but in the end, the film just has a bad script. (Personal opinion)

Comment: This is the third question asking this exact same question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - TBH, I'm not especially happy with the answers in the dupe question, but it's better to dupe them off now that one has an upvoted answer rather than leaving all three open.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah the answers aren't great but we shouldn't have 3 all asking the same thing

Comment: I've answered the reference question in the same way I would answer yours, hope you found it useful.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The fact that the question was asked 3 times means that StackExchange's algorithm for finding similar questions is flawed. If the askers of this question and the other one had seen there was a dupe, they probably would not have asked.

Comment: @LincolnMan SE’s search is more than flawed.